# Plotting contour Maps on Basemap for Python 2.7

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, matplotlib-basemap

I had a question regarding Matplotlib and Basemap in python. I am trying to take a list of latitudes and longitudes and temperatures and plot them on a contour map. I had relative success when I put in data for Alaska. It plotted my data no problem. When I tried putting in data for Alabama, it outputted a completely random map filled with a bunch of garbage data points. I think this may be a problem with the map projection as I subbed out the Alaska data that gave me a working map for the Alabama data that gave me random data. It could be that the differences in coordinates are distorting the temperature values. I'm not exactly sure.

Thanks,
Scott

Here is an example of the Alabama data(first column:ICAO, second column: lat, third column: lon,4th column:temp):

K8A0,34.14,-86.15, 64

KALX,32.55,-85.58, 65

K79J,31.19,-86.24, 75

KANB,33.35,-85.51, 69

```
import urllib2
from urllib2 import urlopen
import cookielib
from cookielib import CookieJar
import time
from Tkinter import *
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.mlab import griddata
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import interpolate
import scipy
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize


FN = '/Users/scottreinhardt/Desktop/airportcodetext1.txt'
data = np.genfromtxt(FN,dtype=None,names=["ICAO","Lat","Lon","Temp"],skip_header=1,delimiter=',')
m = Basemap(projection = 'cyl',llcrnrlon = -73.5, llcrnrlat = 41, urcrnrlon = -81, urcrnrlat = 30, resolution='h')
        # data from http://water.weather.gov/precip/


        # create polar stereographic Basemap instance.
plt.figure(num=None, figsize=(25, 25), dpi=25,edgecolor='k')

xs = np.array(data["Lon"])
ys = np.array(data["Lat"])
z = np.array(data["Temp"])

        #x = x + np.random.normal(scale=1e-8, size=x.shape)
        #y = y + np.random.normal(scale=1e-8, size=y.shape)


        #numcols, numrows = 300, 300
xi = np.linspace(data["Lat"].min(), data["Lat"].max(), 150)
yi = np.linspace(data["Lon"].min(), data["Lon"].max(), 150)
xi, yi = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)
        # Set up a regular grid of interpolation points
#xi, yi = np.linspace(xs.min(), xs.max(), 500), np.linspace(ys.min(), ys.max(), 500)
#xi, yi = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)
        # Interpolate
rbf = scipy.interpolate.Rbf(data["Lat"], data["Lon"], data["Temp"], function='linear')
zi = rbf(xi, yi)
plt.imshow(zi, vmin=z.min(), vmax=z.max(), origin='lower',
extent=[xs.min(), xs.max(), ys.min(), ys.max()])
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Do you really need that wall of imports for the example? Or are you including them in case those are responsible for your issue? Can you add some figures of what you're seeing?

Comment: OK, first you have `xs` <-> `Lon`, then you have `xi` <-> `Lat`. I'm pretty sure that's not good.